# Speed downgrade from 30Mbit to 5Mbit noticeable?

Tags: internet, cable

I use the internet for youtube/netflix/amazon prime, and to do basic browsing. That's it. I very rarely use it to play multiplayer Playstation video games. I share it with another person that basically listens to music and does facebook/social media browsing.

Currently, I have 30Mbit internet, and I would like to cut down my bill. The 5Mbit internet is 40 bucks cheaper, and I'm considering switching to the slower connection.

Taking into consideration my internet usage, will I notice the downgrade? Does this downgrade affect the coverage?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to clarify the speeds i.e. MB/s or mbps

Comment: I did. I called the cable company and they told me I have 30MB internet and that they offer 5MB internet.

Comment: Your asking if you will a notice a different, which means we literally have to guess if your able to tell the difference between the two, which we can't predict.  I certainly would notice the speed difference even when browsing.  with 5 mbps you are unlikely to be able to do 4K streaming with Amazon, YouTube, and Netflix.

Comment: I think this cannot be answered by community. Of course you will recognize a difference, whether this difference is worth 40$ nobody but you can tell.

Comment: Network speed is rarely measured in MB/s. ISPs always use Mbps for the bigger value. 30MBps is 240Mbps whereas 5MBps is only 40Mbps.

Comment: Please guys, use "Mbit". "MB" has always been "Mega Bytes", also make sure to understand that "mbit" is even worse: lower case "m" is used to denote the prefix "milli" (1/1000) and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try it for yourself!

This stackoverflow question, [Simulating Slow Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536249/simulating-slow-internet-connection), have a few interesting top answers, which are given in the context of web page development but would also apply to your question:

1. The simplest seems to try the built-in **Chrome** feature to throttle internet (you can add your custom speed profiles). I believe it only simulates the currently active tab, good to test youtube or netflix.
2. A free application like **NetLimiter** can let you slow down whole applications easily.

Of course, this test is not perfect. In the real-world, more than 1 user may want to stream audio and video at the same time which can lead to dropouts in one or the other if the connection is maxed out, and latencies ("snappiness") can be higher, but it should give you a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain that you won't notice the difference because it's possible the 5Mbit is a maximum connection speed and you won't even get that.

Assuming this is not the case, there'll be little issues with any of the people you use for streaming.  They all recommend a minimum 2Mbit speed so 5 is plenty although you might lose out on the High Definition side of things as there won't be enough bandwidth.

Obviously, your downloads will be slower as well though perhaps not excessively so.  When I download, I don't usually get above 6.5MB download speed (meaning there's plenty of overhead for my children streaming elsewhere while my wife browses the internet on her phone).

At the end of the day, it's going to fall into whether that 5Mbit is the maximum speed or the guaranteed speed.  If it's guaranteed and that's genuinely all you do on your computer, you'll be fine.

Comment: Just commenting on coverage - no, a speed downgrade won't affect wifi coverage.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on many factors, and is also quite subjective.  5 Mbps is less than a megabyte per sec which is pretty slow.  So unless you're watching YouTube in 360 res, I'd say yes.  You'd probably notice even slower speeds during peak times as well.